# How to open each link with content displayed in the same page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a webpage. Here is the concern.
    The page has nav links on left end as a sidebar and the main content area occupies at the center.
    I would want to open each link and its corresponding data should be displayed in the main content area (rest of the data hidden).

Please help me achieve this.Below gives my webpage view

```
<body onload="myFuntion()">
    <div id="header">
        <h3>Michaels Mob App Automation Dashboard</h3>
    </div> 
    <div id="nav">
        <a href="#"  target="_self">iOS</a><br>
        <a name="Android" href="#" target="_self">Android</a><br>
        <a href="#" target="_self">KickOff</a><br>
        <a href="#" target="_self">Run</a><br>
    </div>    
    <div id="section">    
        <table>
            <tr><td> TestCase: </td> <td><input type ="text" name ="TestCase"></td><br>
            <td> Execution Status :  </td> <td><input type ="text" name ="Status"></td></tr><br>

            <p>
                enganunnd?:P
                You might need to add the rows dynamically here using jscript.    
                iOS text    
            </p>
        </table> 
    </div>    
    <div id="footer">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">Graph View</a>/
        <a href="#" target="_blank">List View</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what one refers to as **loading partial views** or **html fragments**.

- jQuery has them: http://api.jquery.com/load/
- AngularJS has them: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude
- you can also do it with `<iframe>`
- you can also use [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Load function if that is an option. http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$("#nav a").click(function(){    
$( "#section" ).load( "pages/test.html" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok to have each link show the same URL in the address bar, and unless you need to get all the data for each "page" off a server, it would be better simply to hardcode each page/section into the one HTML document and use the nav links as triggers to show/hide each section using CSS. This eliminates Ajax calls and would be much quicker to load each section. And you could still populate each section's data dynamically by appending DOM nodes when necessary.